# Method Declerations in Laravel's Facades

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how methods are declared in Laravel's facades. For example, I want to create a user-defined function to index my login page. Firstly, I need to check whether the user is already authenticated. To do that, I will use Laravel's Auth facade.

```
public function indexLogin() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return redirect("/");
    }
}
```

But, when I wanted to learn more about this method, the only thing I came across were declarations made in the PHPDoc section.

```
/*
*
* @method static bool check()
*
*/
```

For this case, I know what the method does but also want to know how it works. I believe the declarations that were made in PHPDoc sections are not enough to run methods.

I checked Laravel's official documentation but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You see at the end of the methods declaration, before the class name declaration there is a PHPDoc :

```
@see \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager
@see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
@see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
@see \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
```

you can check them to know how the method works.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, you can see where the methods come from as pointed out by @xenooooo.

by digging a bit, you cas see that [`check()` is using `user()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.php#L53)

```
/**
 * Determine if the current user is authenticated.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```